# How to set char encoding to utf-8 in JAX-RS Jersey 2.0 Response

Tags: encoding, header, jax-rs, response, jersey-2.0

I`ve written a RESTService that creates a PDF and returns it via Response Object.

Here is my Client:

```
    final Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).post(Entity.entity(building, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8"));
    int responseCode = response.getStatus();
    String fileName = Response.getHeaderString("fileName");
```

And here is the important part of my Web Service method:

```
    return Response.ok(report, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("fileName", reportName).build();
```

My problem is that the umlauts of my filename are just erased:
So for example, if the fileName is : "Gebäude2_2014" the Client will receive "Geb ude2_2014".

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the JAX-RS @Produces in your web service controller and force the UTF-8 encoding. This should fix your issue.

here an example:

```
@Path("/ws/v1") 
@Produces("\"application/json\";charset=utf-8")
public class Documents extends AbstractController {

    @GET
    @Path("/documents/{id}")
    public Response show(@Context UriInfo uri, @PathParam("id") String id) {

    ...
    return Response.ok(report, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("fileName", reportName).build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, success! This was the answer that helped me :') Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to pass a header in response with MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM in my project, and your "Gebäude2_2014" String is read correctly.

In my project all source files are encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: this should me a comment not a answer

Comment: Sorry... I can't comment due to low reputation